# How do I graph $ x=-2(y+1)^2+4$

Tags: calculus

I like to know how do I graph this equation? I am a bit confused since the plus sign within the parenthesis I assume means to gown down on the y axis, and the + 4 outside the parenthesis would mean to move right on the x axis? Then I would stretch it by a factor of 2 and flip the graph on the x axis, thus it essentially would stay in the same place. Am I correct?

Comment: Just turn your graph so that the $x$-axis is the vertical axis and $y$-axis is the horizontal one. Graph like you normally would (i.e. how you would graph $y=-2(x+1)^2+4$). Turn your graph back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get 
$$\begin{align}x=-2(y+1)^2+4&\iff -2(y+1)^2=x-4\\&\iff (y+1)^2=-\frac 12(x-4)\\&\iff \{y-(\color{blue}{-1})\}^2=4\cdot \frac{-1}{8}(x-\color{red}{4}).\end{align}$$

This is a [parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) (here you can see a graph) whose vertex is $(\color{red}{4},\color{blue}{-1})$, the axis of symmetry is $y=\color{blue}{-1}$, the focus is $((-1/8)+\color{red}{4},\color{blue}{-1})$, and the directrix is $x=\color{red}{4}-(-1/8)$.

Comment: Can you show me step by step from the original problem, since I do not understand how you are arriving at your set up.

Comment: @user137452: I added a bit. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I need to look over it real quick.

Comment: @user137452: OK. The link I introduced in my answer has a picture, so you'll be able to graph it.

Comment: How are you getting 1/2 if you are dividing both sides by 2?

Comment: @user137452: Dividing both sides of $-2(y+1)^2=x-4$ by $-2$ gives you $(y+1)^2=(1/(-2))(x-4)$. So, RHS$=-(1/2)(x-4)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16308/discussion-between-user137452-and-mathlove).

Comment: Thank you so much. Just learned something.

Comment: @user137452: You are welcome!

Comment: Maybe this is a question that needs not to be answered but why is it assumed that there is a 1 in front of the quantity (x-4). Is that due to it being divided?

Comment: @user137452: You can see $(x-4)\div (-2)=(x-4)/(-2)=-(x-4)/2=-(1/2)(x-4)$. These are the same.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks again.

Comment: However, if it was being divided by a positive 2 the answer would be x-4 /2 correct?

Comment: @user137452: If $x-4/2$ you wrote means $(x-4)/2$, then it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

No, starting with $x=y^2$

1. Shift down 1
2. Stretch by a factor of 2
3. Reflect in the y-axis
4. Shift right 4

Comment: Okay. So I have to do some algebra and then shift, reflect and stretch? The teacher did not explain this to me. I thought this was another function. Wow!

Comment: It is important that you shift right last or the factor of 2 will change the amount of the shift. Notice that you are starting with $x=y^2$

Comment: I very much like this way of explaining it.  It builds up the final equation step by step from a known parabola.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question, because x is written alone and y is written with all the stuff around it.  Remember that for a parabola, y is the dependent variable so it should be alone on the left side.

$x=-2(y+1)^2+4 $

$x-4=-2(y+1)^2 $

$ -\frac{1}{2}(x-4)=(y+1)^2$

$y+1=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}(x-4)}$

$y=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}(x-4)}-1$

This is going to be a "sideways parabola" with vertical shift $-1$, horizontal shift $4$ to the right, and reflected over the $y$-axis so it is pointing to the left, then horizontally stretched by a factor of 2.

Comment: How did you get negative 1/2 if one divides both sides by 2 to get rid of the -2 that is adjacent to the quantity (y+1)^2? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: I in fact divided by $-2$, which is why the negative sign went away from the right side after that step.

Comment: Oh wait I see what you mean.  Well remember that dividing by $-2$ and multiplying by $-\frac{1}{2}$ are the same thing.

Comment: I understand that but why is it assumed that there is a 1 in front of the quantity (x-4)? How come you are not dividing directly into x-4? Thus getting x-4/2? Can you explain+

Comment: Oh you cannot have $x-\frac{4}{2}$, since $x$ and $-4$ are tied together and cannot be broken.  You can write $-\frac{1}{2}(x-4)$ or $-\frac{x-4}{2}$ or $-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{4}{2}$.  They're all the same thing.

Comment: The same would whole true if the 2 was positive, correct?

Comment: Well, you would have to change your plus and minus signs to compensate for that, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that this is a function of $y$ rather than $x$:

$$f(y) = -2(y+1)^2 + 4.$$

So this is a parabola that opens to the *left* because of the $-2$.  The rightmost point on the parabola occurs at $y=-1$ since this is the value for which $y+1 = 0$.  The particular $x$ value at $y=-1$ is $f(-1) = 4$, so the rightmost point is $(4, -1).$

From there, you can find, for example, $f(0), f(1), f(-2), f(-3),$ to sketch it out.

Comment: "First thing to note is that this is a function of y rather than x" That does not mean anything to me. Can you explain this without using math jargon? Do I need to utilize algebra to get y by itself and then start to sketch the graph?

Comment: What you're describing is what user165130 did, and that's another way of getting the same answer.  I'd recommend that you learn what a function is, because it's an important concept (and if you're taking a class with analytic geometry now, you should have learned about it anyway!)  A function of $y$ has at most one value of $x$ it satisfies for each valid value of $y$.  Notice how user165130 had to worry about the $\pm$?  That's because this parabola is *not* a function of *x*.  There is more than one (up to two) values of $y$ for (all but one) valid value of $x$.