# Sketch the graph $x-3 =-(y+3)^2$

Tags: calculus

$$x-3 = -(y+3)^2$$

$$-(x-3) = (y+3)^2$$

at this point I am stuck. I do not want to square both sides since I then would be getting a square root. I would like to get the equation in the standard form of a quadratic. What is the best way for me to do that?

Comment: Lean your head by 90°.

Comment: Add three to both sides and see the solutions at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891335/how-do-i-graph-x-2y124

Comment: I don't want to do it that way. I want to put it in the standard form of a quadratic. Any way I don't understand if the left side means move the graph 3 places up and the the right side means move the graph 3 places to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start first with the graph of $x=y^2$ or $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$.

[image]

Now, the function $x=-(y+3)^2+3$ is just the function above:

- shifted 3 units to the right
- shifted 3 units down
- reflected in the $y$-axis

[image]

Comment: So the direct opposite of the transformations when the y = and expression?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Well observed!

Comment: I just tried graphing x= -2(y+1)^2 +4 on http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D+-2+%28y%2B1%29%5E2%2B4 and my answer is totally different. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: It should be different.  It's a different equation.

Comment: However, I flipped the parabola so it is opening on the left, and its vertex is at (1,-4). That program has a totally different graph sketched.

Comment: No, it's not a different graph but the horizontal axis is the $y$-axis and the vertical axis is the $x$-axis.